# How can I test an atom feed on localhost?

Tags: testing, restlet, atom-feed

When I try and view an atom feed on localhost, instead of displaying the feed, firefox gives me a choice to add the feed to google reader or my google home page, but I don't think google reader can display feeds from localhost, not sure though.

If I use Chrome it will display the raw xml, but it doesn't attempt to parse it.

What can I use to test my atom feeds on localhost?

[edit]

Thanks to Rubens suggestion in the comments I've used ms interweb explorer and that displays fine. Also, thanks to Anton I've installed a couple of desktop feed aggregators and one does display (SharpREader), but the other(FeedReader) doesn't so I'm assuming there's some validation problem.

I've tried using the w3c atom validator and that reports some errors, mostly to do with the datestamp of entries and the feed not being RFC-3339 compatible and one for namespace prefix 'atom' being undesirable. Would that be a reason for feed aggregators/readers not to display a feed?

What strikes me though is, this is a rather ad hoc way of going about verifying my atom feeds.

ps:

i'm generating the feeds using the restlet 1.1 atom extension.

Comment: You can try [Omea Reader](http://www.jetbrains.com/omea/reader/).

Comment: You could to use IE to display it...

Comment: @Rubens aha! there's an idea!